# The word that comes after

Tags: word

Find a five letter word that can be placed behind each of these words:

> 1) Boiling
>
> 2) Check
>
> 3) Pin
>
> 4) View

Try another one:

> 1) Bill
>
> 2) Card
>
> 3) Side
>
> 4) Skate

And the last one:

> 1) Fire
>
> 2) Rain
>
> 3) Sound
>
> 4) Water

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for the first group is

> point

Second one:

> board

Last one:

> proof (not sure ...)

Comment: hehe sniped on the last one

Comment: Yeah, you posted it a few seconds earlier but I found it without looking at your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Last one(possibly)

> proof

Though

> rainproof is a bit uncommon.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that one