# A Riley Rebus As Suggested By Duck

Tags: rebus

This is gonna be a Riley rebus suggested by @Duck (Thanks) 
 Be sure to check out some of his great riddles and puzzles like [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69417/just-another-riley-riddle) and [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69019/the-word-that-comes-after) :D

[image]

Note :

> I will probably (Definitely) post another one of these. [It's here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71349/riley-rebus-2-coming-up) :D
>
> Will also add hints if nobody gets if after a while

Small Hint :

> Don't take things too *literally*

Another Small Hint :

> The Suffix picture is a game called agario

Specific Hint for Prefix :

> It's a way of measuring something that is also related to a circle

Comment: @Duck Lol, no problem mate. Thanks for the idea (you should make one too) :D

Comment: @KevinL what i do is paste the pictures side by side in paint or word and then save it as a single file. Then upload it. You might wanna try that

Comment: Hmm, does that work for mac users too?

Comment: It should. You are basically keeping all the pictures in a single line and uploading it as a single file instead of multiple pictures.

Comment: Idk why, but when I clicked on the merged file, this doesn't allow me to do so. I hope somebody can fix this for me :) @R.D

Comment: Windows Master Race

Comment: Thank you to the person who has edited my question (whoever that is) :)

Comment: You play Agar.io? :D

Comment: Of course, it's a nice game :) @user477343

Comment: If you like agar.io there are thousands more io games, and you can go to iogames.space to browse them

Comment: Oh thanks, never heard of that website :D @Duck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be something like

> Radio?

Prefix

> Rad (for radian)

Infix

> di

Suffix

> Io

Comment: The word is correct but...the prefix and suffix isn't the intended one

Comment: Yay, Loved the puzzle, I need hint in the right direction though... @KevinL

Comment: Hmm, you mean I should add one more hint?

Comment: Or just a hint in the comments? :)

Comment: Ok then ROT 13 (lbhe cersvk vf abj pbeerpg, ohg vg vf abg enq sbe enqvhf, vg'f enq sbe .... Nyfb, svaq nabgure jbeq gung svgf gur vasvk cvpgher) :D

Comment: Thanks! rot13(pbhyq gur vasvk or "qv" yvxr gur onggrel qvrq?) :D

Comment: Yep that's correct. Now all that's left is the prefix part :)

Comment: Btw, if you need some more help, just tell me so :D

Comment: Is it rot13(enq)? @KevinL :)

Comment: Yes it is still that but the explanation is wrong. Where you derive it from is incorrect :)

Comment: Nope it's not derived from the answer itself mate. Your prefix is supposed to be derived from a certain element of a circle :D

Comment: If u don't want to know the answer, don't decrypt this ROT13 (enq sbe enqvna) :)

Comment: Ohhh, thanks so much that makes sense!! :D Great puzzle, I'm also checking out the new rebus you posting :)

Comment: Thanks, Hope you like the second part too. Btw, I'll accept ur answer tomorrow as usual :D

Comment: I pressed the wrong thing on my phone and now I'm getting "You last voted on this answer 17 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited." Could someone edit the post so I can remove my downvote.

Answer (score 6):

A wacky Guess-

> Pillow Fight

Explanation:

> first pic has to do with circles, circumference, diameters etc. hence Pi,
>  Second one Low (Low battery),
>  third looks like the leader board of some game, hence Fight.

Comment: Nope that's very far from the intended answer. Still (+1) :)

Comment: ha ha, it was a bit of a far fetched guess :D

Answer (score 3):

Could this be

> Dialoguer

First image

> Dia for diameter

Second

> Lo(w) for low battery

Third

> Guer : the game is agar.io

So

> Dia + low + agar = dialoguer

Comment: unfortunately incorrect :)

Comment: It's a good puzzle!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should I try to make another one in the near future?

Comment: @KevinL Definitely!

Comment: Oh ok then. Gonna start thinking for another one and probably post it tomorrow :D @R.D

Comment: Yes, most definitely! Tbh, I was getting a little tired of the usual Rileys (maybe coz I find them hard :P ). But this one's good, it makes the same puzzle more interesting! :)

Comment: Make it slightly easy though XD

Comment: OK, Riley Rebus coming up tomorrow (maybe) :D @nikki

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if i can do that. I was gonna make it even harder XD @R.D