# Riley Rebus #2 Coming Up!

Tags: rebus

Another Riley Rebus since the [last one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71296/a-riley-rebus-as-suggested-by-duck) went quite well
[image]

Hint :

> The answer consists of only one word

Extra Hint :

> It's not what you first think :)

More Hints :

> The flavor of the cup noodles do not matter

Comment: I'm using windows 7 and it won't let me drag and drop the pictures or use the link, and on an asus

Comment: Also it seems like the suffix is rot13(ber)

Comment: Nope sorry that's wrong :) @Duck

Comment: Oh, ok I'll be working on it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it may be

> Instagram

Prefix:

> Inst, as in instant ramen

Infix:

> Tag, the game

Suffix:

> Gram, that's a gram of gold!

Comment: nice answer, this might be it.

Comment: @odofjsh You beat me by a minute.

Comment: Wait, who is faster? odofjsh or rhsquared ???

Comment: just found out u were faster. Congrats and btw, I usually accept answers after a day :)

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is

> Chickening out

Prefix

> Chicken

Infix

> Playing = ing

Suffix

> This is where I am doubtful. Gold is measured in carat which in turn is derived from "carob" so it may be a bit of a stretch to make it sound like out, but it kinda does.

Comment: Yeah maybe the suffix is incorrect, but I think the prefix is right

Comment: The infix? @Duck

Comment: I'm not sure... though looking at Kevin's other posts it doesn't seem like he has done that before

Comment: Not the answer. Every part is wrong unfortunately :D @R.D

Comment: Ooof! Time to look at it from another angle.

Comment: This is a small hint for u : the infix lacks specifics. What could I mean?? :D

Comment: is the prefix Rot13(enzra)? @KevinL

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid Nope :D

Comment: @KevinL it still is a bit vague to me. Will wait for hints

Comment: Maybe the answer is rot13(anehgb) lol.

Comment: Gonna make another hint after this. Btw, naruto is definitely not the answer mate XD @R.D

Comment: XD I know. @KevinL but it's better than nothing

Comment: Yup. Just added another hint here. I'm hoping this will be much much harder than the first one. Will probably make a part 3 in the near future :D @R.D

Comment: Hm. Has the first one been solved? I've looked at the supposedly correct, but yet unticked answer and couldn't really make heads or tails of the 'fixes. I'm not sure what this one being "much much harder" really means.

Answer (score 4):

Is it?

> Pentagram

Prefix

> A bit far-fetched but Noodles => Pasta => Penne

Infix

> tag => game of tag

Suffix

> gram => a gram of gold

Comment: Nope sorry not the intended answer. Still, have a (+1) :D

Comment: Your profile picture is scary... $(+1)$

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by the answer given by @helix

> Instagram

Prefix

> Instant noodles -> Insta

Infix

> Game of tag -> tag

Suffix

> 1 gram of gold ->gram

Comment: Edit : Who is faster? U or odofjsh (the time doesn't show up on my screen) :)

Comment: @KevinL I was slower by a minute.

Comment: Ouch, that must've been painful. Sorry mate gonna have to accept the fastest one :D

Comment: @KevinL That's only right.

Comment: Yep will do so. Still, gonna (+1) your answer!

Answer (score 2):

My mind is not able to go beyond this:

> Ramen + tag + bar = Ramentagbar? :P

Comment: This is wrong but there is a part of your answer that is correct (Not gonna say it) :D