# Looking For Riley Rebus #3? It's Right Here!

Tags: knowledge, rebus

This the part 3 of the Riley Rebus series. Be sure to check out [part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71349/riley-rebus-2-coming-up) and [part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71296/a-riley-rebus-as-suggested-by-duck?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Prefix + Infix + Suffix :

[image] [image] [image]

To Clarify :

> The answer is only 1 word

Hint :

> Trust me, it's not what you first think

Additional Small Hint :

> The third picture is an animal, but that wasn't what I meant

Another Hint :

> The leaves in the second picture do not matter

4th Super Small Hint :

> I know it's obvious, but in case you're wondering, the first image has been answered correctly by almost all who have tried

Medium Hint :

> You should not see the 2nd image as *tea*, even though it still is tea

More Hints :

> The third image is an eagle with a specific color (will not tell as it will make things too obvious), but that's not all, is it?

Another specific hint for image 2 :

> Try looking at the tea picture from another *person's* perspective

Comment: Is the prefix re?

Comment: Can't say anything mate. Try posting your answer and I'll see whether it's right or not :D

Comment: Does this rebus require knowledge? i.e., would it be appropriate if this rebus included the `knowledge` tag or not?

Comment: Well, it does include just a little knowledge (very little). I'll add it though, thanks for the suggestion :) @user477343

Comment: Well, either way, this has proven to be a bit tricky. This is a nice Riley Rebus :P

Comment: Thanks mate :D Guess I made this one too hard after all @user477343

Comment: @KevinL is it reopen?

Comment: Nope, not the answer @NiranjPatel

Comment: Wow! I never thought Riley rebuses would be so good! Unfortunately, my device isn't allowing me to paste / drag and drop / link the pictures

Comment: Same number of votes as answers :P

Comment: LOL, yeah I just noticed that XD @YoutRied

Comment: Maybe another hint for the last day of the bounty?

Comment: Don't forget to accept the correct answer!

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that lol :D @u_ndefined

Comment: Unfortunately, QuantumTwinkie has already given the correct answer :) @YoutRied

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got it!

> Recharge

Prefix

> Re (refresh)

Infix

> Cha, for Cha tea in Chinese.

suffix

> Rge(Royal Golden Eagle)

Comment: My bad, didn't see your answer really!

Comment: +1 for you to figure this out first :D

Comment: EDIT : As u answered first, you will be given the bounty and the checkmark 1 day before the bounty expires :D

Comment: @KevinL I don't understand how the asnwer for the infix relates to the last hint. Could you explain please?

Comment: BTW, Quantum Twinkie you got the answer correct but the infix and suffix not intended

Comment: I wanted the ROT13 (vasvk gb or pun (vg zrnaf grn va puvarfr) naq gur fhssvk gb or ETR (juvpu vf fubeg sbe Eblny Tbyqra Rntyr). Vs cbffvoyr, cyrnfr vapyhqr guvf ba lbhe cbfg gbb.) :D

Comment: @GiaFil7 What I meant by other person was specifically a ROT13 (Puvarfr Crefba --> Grn = Pun va puvarfr)

Comment: @KevinL, all fixed :D, great puzzle!

Comment: Thanks, be sure to look forward to receiving the bonus rep :D

Comment: @KevinL, oh I am! :D

Answer (score 10):

Let me try, is it

> RETIRED

prefix:

> it is a repeat or refresh icon, so I think the prefix is RE
>  (I just see Duck's comment about the prefix, but I found the answer myself )

infix:

> a tea  > TI

suffix:

> I am not really sure, but I think it is a RED hawk

Comment: For the suffix rot13(gur oveq vf n tbyqra rntyr)

Comment: aah.. seriously? It looks so similar to me :)

Comment: Nope that's incorrect unfortunately :D

Comment: Still wrong mate :D

Comment: I nearly made the same mistake regarding the suffix too, actually, hahah; though looking at other answers, I saw it was likely I misinterpreted. $(+1)$ nonetheless :P

Answer (score 9):

Probably a stretch but,

> Rebus?

Prefix

> Re, as stated by others

Infix

> **B**-Tea? 
> [image: B-tea]

Suffix

> A golden **eagle**. The bald **eagle** is the national bird of the United States, or **US**.

Comment: This one is my favorite

Comment: Nope it's incorrect :D

Answer (score 8):

Ok, here is my answer and clarification:

> RECHARGE

1. > RE for the first image
2. > Instead of Tea - I used the word chai which is another popular name for it, though I have changed it to char to make more sense as a word
3. > GE - because the bird is a Golden Eagle

Comment: +1 from me because it seems pretty right anyways :D

Comment: EDIT : (+1) but unfortunately, QuantumTwinkie answered first :)

Comment: Good thing is, my answer is correct. I am glad about that. :)

Comment: I think it's unnecessary/annoying using rot13 inside spoiler blocks...

Comment: Makes sense. Noted. I thought this is the norm around here, still new to this.

Answer (score 6):

My wild guess:

> Retina

Prefix:

> A replay button, hence Re.

Infix:

> A cup of tea, hence ti.

Suffix (Not so sure about this one):

> A golden eagle which can be found in North America, hence na.

EDIT:
Regarding the last hint:

> Is the infix D? Because when you look at cup from the opposite side of the "table" it kind of looks like the letter D

Comment: Incorrect but other than the prefix part, you may ALMOST have one other correct part :D

Comment: @KevinL ahh, I think by ALMOST, you mean (ROT13) gur cersvk, orvat ERJVAQ naq abg ERGVAN? :D

Comment: Actually, I meant what I exactly wrote :D @user477343

Comment: @KevinL I've edited after the last hint. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @GiaFil7 Unfortunately, you're kinda off-track here but nice try :D

Answer (score 6):

Maybe:

> Recovered (RE+CUP+BIRD when said with a mouthful of porridge!)

Comment: $(+1)$ for the humour, hahah :P

Comment: Nope still not right :D

Answer (score 6):

Frankly, I cheated by looking at the "super close" answer of @jc1850 so I'll say:

> retie or return

**Prefix**

> Re, which everyone got

**Infix**

> T, because it's a cup of tea

**Suffix**

> ie, because it's the bird's *eye* hence the hint that "it's not the animal" or
>  urn, if this is an erne ([sea eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_eagle)).

Though I really think the English language could use a new word:

> turncuphawk which I define to mean a puzzle that makes everyone beat their heads against a wall.

Comment: $(+1)$ for not only the answer, but that last part, hahah :D

Comment: The eagle was a lie all along.

Comment: Not the correct answer unfortunately :D

Comment: @KevinL I had one last guess, based on the supposition that this is a sea eagle.

Comment: @HughMeyers Just took a look at your new answer but that's not it :D

Answer (score 5):

Are you a:

> Reticle?

Reason:

> Re(Replay) + Tea + Eagle.
>  Sounds similar to Reticle.
>  Also fits the title because if you are looking for something through a scope you aim at the target using the reticle.

Comment: Nope that's wrong :)

Answer (score 3):

**Partial**

> I think the suffix is **GE** (**G**olden **E**agle)

**Second Attempt**

Could it be:

> Recipe

**Prefix**

> **Re**try

**Infix**

> You sip (cip) tea

**Suffix**

> **E**agle

Comment: Super close mate but that's not it :D

Comment: I've had another go

Comment: Still not correct sorry :D

Answer (score 3):

Possibly?

> Research

Prefix like all before have said

> re

Infix

> hard to feel good about this but I believed it could be sip... but only the s

Suffix

> This is what I feel the best about - perch

Justification of the hint -

> The third picture is an animal, but that wasn't what I meant
>  Perch is both the action the bird is involved in and a type of fish.  So it is an animal but not what the creator was intentionally referencing.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the intended answer :D

Answer (score 3):

### HERE I GO

> remugle

Prefix:

> Re

Infix:

> Mug - its a mug

Suffix:

> Le - Its a golden eag**le**

Comment: I like this one :) +1

Comment: Not the correct answer :)

Comment: It's a cup. Not a mug. Mugs are larger.

Answer (score 3):

Answer

> **Refulge**. It means someone or something that shines or glows.

Prefix

> RE. Icon meaning **re**turn, **re**peat, etc.

Infix

> FUL. The cup is full.

Suffix

> GE. Golden Eagle. Based on other answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial**

> I'm guessing the 2nd photo is actually minty, mint+tea. I was thinking redo-minty, as in rudimentary, but the hawk doesn't fit in well with that... Perhaps someone can take that and go from there.

Comment: unfortunately mint-tea is not the 2nd photo :D

Answer (score 2):

I'll try another answer. Is it

> RETWEET

prefix:

> it is a replay or refresh icon, so I think the prefix is RE
>  (I just see Duck's comment about the prefix, but I found the answer myself )

infix:

> a tea  > T

suffix:

> I am not really sure (again), is a bird means a TWEET?

Comment: Nope incorrect mate :)

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

> Could the suffix be CA for Canada?

Comment: Sorry that's not right :D

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> Refrain

First pic

> Reload/**Refr**esh

Second pic

> Tea is also known as ch**ai**

Third pic

> Golden eagle, **N**orth America. Credits to GiaFil7 on this part

Comment: Nope incorrect :)

Answer (score 2):

Let me try and thanks to [jc1850](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52152/jc1850) for hint

Could it be:

> Resign

**Prefix**

> **Re**load

**Infix**

> have a **si**p of tea

**Suffix**

> **G**olde**N** eagle

Comment: Nope not the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer:

> Recuperate?

First image:

> "Re", as in your hint you state it's the answer most people have given for this

Second image:

> "Cup", a cup of tea (can't be tea, according to your hint)

Third image:

> "Perate" sounds like "parrot", but you clarified in your hint that it's an eagle?

Comment: unfortunately incorrect :D

Answer (score 0):

Grasping at straws here

> Repurpose

Prefix

> Re (redo/refresh)

Infix

> Pur (pour, the tea from the POV of the waiter)

Sufix

> Pose (what the bird is doing unsuspectingly)

Answer (score 0):

When everyone's trying their hand at it, I will too. :P

Is the answer

> ReCapture

Prefix

> Re

Infix:

> Cup (cup of tea

Suffix:

> Ture (The bird is a golden eagle, but that's not all, it is a 'true eagle', modify it a little to get 'ture')