# Riley Rebuses that Share a Common Theme

Tags: visual

**[Riley Rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71296/a-riley-rebus-as-suggested-by-duck)**, started by [Kevin L](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/45524/kevin-l), is like a Riley Riddle but with images instead.

Here are 5 Riley Riddles that share a common theme. **Can you find out the words and the common theme?**

> [image: riley rebus]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The theme is **Mineral Gemstones**

Answer:

> $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline\textbf{Prefix} & \textbf{Infix} & \textbf{Suffix} & \textbf{Word} \\ \hline\text{Ag} & \text{Ga} & \text{gate} & \text{Agate} \\ \hline\text{Sun} & \text{St} & \text{One} & \text{Sunstone} \\ \hline\text{Spin} & \text{Ne} &  \text{L}& \text{Spinel} \\ \hline\text{Sap} & \text{Ph} & \text{Hire} & \text{Sapphire} \\ \hline\text{Lab} & \text{Rad+Or} & \text{Rite} & \text{Labradorite} \\ \hline\end{array}$$

In detail:

> 1. [Ag (Chemical symbol for Silver)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver) + [Ga (Chemical symbol for Gallium)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallium) + Gate = [AGATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agate)
>  2. Sun + St (Street) + One = SUNSTONE
>  3. Spin + NE (North East) + L (Cyrillic L @jafe) = SPINEL
>  4. [Sap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sap) + PH (Philippines) + Hire = SAPPHIRE
>  5. Lab + Rad (Radian) + [Or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OR_gate) + Rite (Right) = LABRADORITE

Comment: 2,4 and 5 are formed by direct concatenation. This doesn't seem to be the case in 1.

Comment: @Tojrah I think it doesn't have to direct concatenation as long as it fits the prefix/infix/suffix.

Comment: Picture 2(infix) could be improved. A street is a road in a city or town, usually with houses or buildings, and often with sidewalks. What is pictured is only a road.